# Haskell fmap functor

Tags: haskell, functor, algebraic-data-types

I have a problem with functors over queue based on designated algebraic datastructures.

```
data DQueue a = Empty | Enqueue a (DQueue a)
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read)


instance Functor DQueue
  where
    fmap f (Enqueue x xs) = Enqueue (f x) $ fmap f xs

instance Foldable DQueue
  where
    foldr = error "not done"

sample1 :: DQueue Int
sample1 =  Enqueue 5 $ Enqueue 7 $ Enqueue 9 Empty
```

and result should be like that:

```
fmap (+1) sample1 ~?= Enqueue 6 (Enqueue 8 (Enqueue 10 Empty))
foldr (+) 0 sample1 ~?= 24
```

fmap seems to be logicaly correct but I get an error:
Non-exhaustive patterns in function fmap

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because you're missing an alternative for `Empty`.

Comment: I strongly recommend turning on warnings will `-Wall`. So many little mistakes are caught by this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Functor` instance definition is non-exhaustive because it doesn't handle all possible type constructors of `DQueue`. Namely, it is missing a pattern matching `Empty`. You need to define how to handle `fmap` when your value is `Empty`.

Comment: Could you help With foldr Implementation?

Comment: Stack Overflow posts are best when limited to a focused question. If you have followup questions on the code or need guidance, please open another question or visit the [FreeNode Haskell channel](https://wiki.haskell.org/IRC_channel).

Comment: Sorry you are right.  I've Marked this question As solved.

Answer (score 4):

The error speaks for itself: your definition for `Functor` is defined as:

```
data DQueue a = Empty | Enqueue a (DQueue a) deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

instance Functor DQueue where
    fmap f (Enqueue x xs) = Enqueue (f x) $ fmap f xs
```

There is however the possibility (in this case, if I understand your data-structure correctly, the certainty) that eventually `fmap` will be fed an `Empty` instance. You thus have to expand your definition to:

```
instance Functor DQueue where
    fmap f (Enqueue x xs) = Enqueue (f x) $ fmap f xs
    fmap _ Empty = Empty
```

---

Most compilers support a flag such that the compiler complains about non-exhaustive patterns, for the *Glasgow Haskell Compiler* (`ghc`), you can use the `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` flag. For example:

```
$ ghc queue.hs -fwarn-incomplete-patterns
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( queue.hs, queue.o )

queue.hs:7:5: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘fmap’: Patterns not matched: _ Empty
Linking queue ...
```