# Haskell fmap foldr for algebraic datastructures

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I need to implement code to cover few tests but I am stucked with few small problems.

The logic for foldr functions seem to be correct but I get an error during compiling.

This error means that my code does not cover some cases for foldr functions.

The code is given below:

```
module QueueFunctor where

import Test.HUnit (runTestTT,Test(TestLabel,TestList,TestCase),(~?=))
import Data.Char (toUpper)
import Prelude hiding (foldr)
import Data.Foldable (Foldable, foldr)

data DQueue a = Empty | Enqueue a (DQueue a)
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read)



instance Functor DQueue
      where
        fmap f (Enqueue x xs) = (length xs == 0) then Empty else Enqueue (f x) $ fmap f xs

instance Foldable DQueue
  where
    foldr f result (Enqueue x xs) = if (length xs == 0) then f result Empty else foldr f (f x result) xs


-- | Tests a few examples.
main :: IO ()
main = do
    testresults <- runTestTT tests
    print testresults


sample1 :: DQueue Int
sample1 =  Enqueue 1 $ Enqueue 2 $ Enqueue 3 $ Enqueue 4 Empty

sample2 :: DQueue String
sample2 = Enqueue "a" $ Enqueue "b" $ Enqueue "c" $ Enqueue "d" Empty

sample3 :: DQueue [Int]
sample3 = Enqueue [1,2,3] $ Enqueue [4,5,6] Empty

tests :: Test
tests = TestLabel "DQueueTest" (TestList [
        fmap (+1) sample1 ~?= Enqueue 2 (Enqueue 3 (Enqueue 4 (Enqueue 5 Empty))),
        fmap (map toUpper) sample2 ~?= Enqueue "A" (Enqueue "B" (Enqueue "C" (Enqueue "D" Empty))),
        fmap (length) sample3 ~?= Enqueue 3 (Enqueue 3 Empty),
        foldr (+) 0 sample1 ~?= 10,
        foldr (++) "" sample2 ~?= "abcd",
        foldr (\a b ->(+) b (length a)) 0 sample3 ~?= 6
    ])
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell fmap functor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987890/haskell-fmap-functor) -- You asked this question a couple hours ago.

Comment: Please do not change the question after you have received an answer with an updated error message. It would be best to start a new question. As it stands, the current answer makes it look like they never even read the question.

Comment: Okay, I will create a new one. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both instance declarations for `Foldable` and `Functor` are missing patterns that match the `Empty` constructor.

You'll need to add code for

```haskell
foldr f result Empty = ...
-- and ...
fmap f Empty = ...
```

Non-exhaustive means that there are patterns which are unmatched which can cause your program to crash.

Comment: Hm you are right, it solved issue with fmap but not with foldr.

Comment: Take a look at [how `Maybe` implements `foldr` for the `Nothing` constructor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html). Your implementation will probably look similar.